# Fabric.js nothing renders in canvas

Tags: fabricjs

So I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, and I'm equally sure I have no idea what it is.

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.2/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="starmap"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('starmap');
console.log(canvas);
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f00', top: 10, left: 10 }));

canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
canvas.renderAll();

</script>
```

Using Fabric 2.2.2, which is loading into the DOM.  All I'm getting is a 300x150 canvas with no content.

Comment: Check the snippet , its working. What was your issue?

Comment: Canvas renders blank.  Tried it in a couple different browsers with the same result.

Comment: is this snippet working for you?

Comment: Snippet is working here

Comment: I had this problem when I  placed script code  in  head.  When I put into  the  page 's 
 body  tag  ,   it worked